# Text changing line height for no reason when scrolling?

Tags: flutter

weird problem here.

I have a Text widget within a SingleChildScrollview.

```
SingleChildScrollView [ ... other things ... ] 

Column _descriptionColumn(Person person) {
  return Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60.0),
      child: Text(

        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ',

        softWrap: true,

        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 11,
            inherit: false,
            fontFamily: 'Spartan',
            color: Colors.black),
        maxLines: null,
        textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
      ),
    )
  ]);
}
```

Now when scrolling, the text changes line spacing when close to the border of the scrollview. In fact it has the correct line spacing when almost off screen, then  for some reason it widens when closer to the middle of the screen (in which case it becomes too big, will overflow all containers etc etc).

What could be the reason for that?

Things tried with no effect:

- defining strutStyle to force line height,
- disabling style inheritance,
- disabling TextAlign.justify.
- changing the SingleChildScrollview into a ListView and ListView.builder
- removing the ConstrainedBox around the SingleChildScrollView

**Not setting the fontSize seems to mitigate it (jumps less).**

**EDIT: I'm starting to become pretty convinced this might be a bug in the HTML renderer. ---- when switched to the canvasKit renderer the described issue doesn't happen.**

This is Flutter 2.2.0 Web in Chrome (html renderer)

[image]

EDIT: more code

```
class PeopleList extends StatelessWidget { //top level
  final List<Person> people;

  const PeopleList({Key? key, required this.people})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 500),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(children: _buildList(people)))));
  }
}


List<Widget> _buildList(List<Person> people) {
  List<Widget> output = [];
  people.forEach((element) {
    output.add(_personBox(element));
  });

  return output;
}


Widget _personBox(Person person) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Card(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
        _personInfoColumn(person),
        _separatorColumn(),
        Expanded(child: _descriptionColumn(person))
      ]),
    )),
  );
}



Column _descriptionColumn(Person person) {
  return Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60.0),
      child: Text(


        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',

        softWrap: true,

        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 11,
            inherit: false,
            fontFamily: 'Spartan',
            color: Colors.black),
        maxLines: null
      ),
    )
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? Maybe your `SingleChildScrollView` also. Just by showing your text won't help.

Comment: Sure, please see the EDIT.

Comment: Try wrapping your text with `FittedBox()` and `ConstrainedBox()` is needed for your logic? I think that might be doing things with `SingleChildScrollView()`

Comment: The ConstrainedBox keeps the boxes from going full screen width, which would look good on mobile but not so much on desktop. They also need to be able to scale down on smaller screens (hence maxWidth). I could try to constrain the width of children instead of the whole ScrollView though. I'll try wrapping the Text in a FittedBox.

Comment: Ok so wrapping the Text in a FittedBox makes the Text disappear. Removing the ConstrainedBox completely also doesn't change this behaviour.